# pass C++ double array to embedded python efficiently without NumPy

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am extending C++ with embedded Python. How to efficiently pass an array of doubles?

Currently I create a tuple:

```
std::vector<double> a(len);
...
PyObject* pInput = PyTuple_New(len);
for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    PyTuple_SetItem(pInput, i, PyFloat_FromDouble(a[i]));
```

Is there a more efficient way for large arrays (e.g. `len > 1000000`)? I do not want to use NumPy. What datatype to use on the Python side then? Is it possible to construct an object of type `array.array` (binary Python array)? Or what other (Python) type should I construct in the C++ code, which could then be converted to `array.array` on the Python side.